# Как определить что страница запрошена POST методом?

Tags: php

Как определить что страница запрошена POST методом?

Comment: Kremchik всё правильно ответил, только вот не "страница запрошена", а данные переданы методом POST. Или же - при передаче данных, был использован метод запроса POST

Comment: @Deonis почему нет? Вроде ж логично все. Произошел запрос к странице, был указан метод POST. Данные вообще могли не быть переданы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Очень просто:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // это был пост
}
```

Answer (score 0):

POST - скрытый метод предачи данных
GET - запрос же отображается в адресной строке когда обрабатывается и по этому он открытый

Comment: вопрос немного не о том и не в ту степь